Port not working using systemd
I'm migrating to a Linux Red Hat 9 server and can't get my .NET web application to work on a specific port (8343) when using systemd. I'm specifically using Kestrel.
I see the following error when debugging:
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.CertificatePathWatcher[4]
      Created directory watcher for '/etc/pki/tls'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.CertificatePathWatcher[5]
      Created directory watcher for '/etc/pki/tls/cert.pfx'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Failed to bind to http://[::]:8343 (IPv6Any). Attempting to bind to http://0.0.0.0:8343 instead.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:8343

It doesn't bind right away when the service starts up and then eventually listens on https://0.0.0.0:8343. When I try and go to https://someurl.com:8343/ or https://someurl.com:8343/healthcheck its not coming up.
Here's my service file and shell script below:
#TestApp.service

[Unit]
Description=TestApp
Documentation=''
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=someuser
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c /www/someurl.com/TestApp/app.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


#app.sh

#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
cd /www/someurl.com/TestApp/app
set -o pipefail
Kestrel__Endpoints__Https__Certificate__Path="/etc/pki/tls/cert.pfx" Kestrel__Endpoints__Https__Certificate__Password="**********" Kestrel__Endpoints__Https__Url="https://*:8343" DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT="Staging" ./TestApp 2>&1 | tee /apps/logs/TestApp/output_&now.log

Any insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

The IP address ([::1]) is an IPv6 address. unfotunately, your upstream network doesn't support IPv6.
To disable IPv6, open Settings->Network->Your interface->IPv6 Tab, and UNcheck "Enable IPv6". Save your change, then turn the interface OFF, 1breath, ON, to ensure the new setting takes effect.

@waltinator shouldn't a default IPv6 address still be avaiable as long as the local machine supports IPv6?

Take systemd out of the picture. Are you able to start this manually? It's not clear that systemd has anything to do with this question.

@waltinator ::1 is the loopback address. It's not relying on upstream network. Furthermore it amazes me how you know what the upstream network supports and not.
